# Can't expand div horizontally with Native Base on React Native Web

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to expand a div when I am testing for mobile sizes:

[image: Mobile image]

However, as you can see, it is completely in one tiny part of the screen. This isn't happening on larger, desktop sizes, just mobile sizes.

My layout looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Row, Column, Container } from 'native-base'
import Header from 'app/components/header/Header'
import Footer from 'app/components/footer/Footer'
const Layout = (props: { children: any }) => {
  return (
    <Container w="100%" flexGrow={1}>
      {props.children}
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

I've tried using all sorts of elements, as seen above, currently I am using a `<Container />`

My `<Footer />` looks like this:

```
const MainFooter = () => {
  return (
    <Column bg="#171717" py={50} px={[108, 90]} flexGrow={1} w="100%">
       ...
    </Column>
  )
}
```

The only way that I can get the full width is if I set it explicitly, but that isn't a great solution, because I want the width to be able to resize when a user expands or contracts the window.

What exactly needs to be done to expand the width more? I've been trying to find any potential solution and I can't find anything that ends up working.

This is on a NextJS site if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably was with my viewport. Adding this to the page header fixed the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```